# How to return only articles that has translations inside Twig template, Rainlab.Translate module

Tags: php, oop, twig, octobercms

I am using `rainlab.translate` plugin in my website and have two languages `en` and `ka` (English and Georgian Languages).

Also I have `Article` Model which has some `$translatable` fields (like `title`).

Some of my Articles are only in Georgian language, and I do not want to show them in English version once I switch the language.

So what I am trying to do is:

```
{% for article in articles %}
   {% if article.lang(activeLocale).title %}
      // Then Display Article
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this does not work as by default if `article.title` does not have translation it returns default string.

Is there any solution to do this on Twig Template?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did one solution which works but if you have any other you are welcome :)

```
{% for post in articles %}
   {% set post = post.noFallbackLocale.lang(activeLocale) %}

   {% if post.title %}
       // then display post
   {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i guess if this do the job then its good, i don't see any problem in it, may be you keep using it :)